# March '13 Public Update possilby interrupted?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, installation, cumulative-update

I was creating a new SP 2013 Enterprise installation on Friday, and the March '13 PU was still running when I left Friday evening. Our sysadmin did not know this, and rebooted my server on Saturday to move some VMs around.  I'm sure the "main" part of the install was done - but I forget if there were any final prompts late in the package install process.  Does anyone remember this?  Any event to (not) look for in the Events log to see if it actually "finished?"  Otherwise I'll probably blow everything away and start again from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would check the system /setup logs if you get a clue.
Also i would try to run the March PU binaries again, if last time its completed successfully then it will tell you otherwise will start installing.

Comment: I ran the installer again and it said everything was already installed. I had some other system errors and LSS I am in the middle of a new reinstall.  Thanks for the help.